# How to add a link to the tax term in the admin Edit page?

Tags: admin, notices

I have a custom taxonomy, 'genre.'

I'd like my editors, from the 'Edit Genre' screen (in the admin), to be able to link to the front end page for that genre/term.

So, at the top of the 'Edit Genre' page there would be a link such as:

See this page: mysite.com/genre/fiction

- or - if I could have a 'Preview Changes' button, as in the Post Edit screen.

Possible?

Note, I've seen some solutions that suggest putting in a dummy custom meta box, using the description as the text/link.  Is there a way to do the above without doing the meta box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic hook [`{taxonomy}_term_edit_form_top`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_term_edit_form_top/)  can be used to output a link to the term's archive page.

Since we're dealing with terms under the `genre` taxonomy, we will attach our callback to the `genre_term_edit_form_top` hook.

```
/**
 * Adds a link to top of edit term form for terms under the
 * genre taxonomy.
 *
 * @param object $tag      Current taxonomy term object.
 * @param string $taxonomy Current $taxonomy slug.
 */
add_action( 'genre_term_edit_form_top', 'wpse_add_genre_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse_add_genre_link( $tag, $taxonomy ) {
  $term_link = get_term_link( $tag ) ; ?>

  <div class="term-link-container">
    <strong><?php _e( 'See this page:', 'text-domain' ); ?></strong>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ) ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term_link ); ?></a>
  <div><?php
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  This is one of those less-known hooks with little written about it out in the web sphere.

Comment: You got it, Leora! Don't hesitate to browse the source to look for goodies like this. Personally, I trend look at the source before searching the web. The inline docs are top notch.